# Forward requests for specific port to VPN client

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, port-forwarding

I have a problem where I need support, but the hard part is that I don't know WHERE it's wrong. I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server running at my home network and a VPS with Ubuntu Server at a hosting server. The Raspberry Pi has an OpenVPN Client and the VPS an OpenVPN Server. The Client is connected to the Server since I can see it in /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log.

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sun Feb 16 09:41:43 2020
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
client1,37.201.227.34:28237,3610,3478,Sun Feb 16 09:41:38 2020
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.8.0.6,client1,37.201.227.34:28237,Sun Feb 16 09:41:38 2020
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

I want to forward requests to the VPS with Port 9000 to the VPN client. However, it always times out like it doesn't forward the request.

I have `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` set in sysctl and this is the content of `/etc/ufw/before.rules` (I also tried exchanging 37.201.xxx with 10.8.0.6 but without any luck)

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#

# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 37.201.227.34:9000
-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p udp -m udp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 37.201.227.34:9000

# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to venet0 (change to the interface you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines


# allow all on loopback
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow dhcp client to work
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

# START OPENVPN RULES
-A FORWARD -d 37.201.227.34/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 37.201.227.34/32 -p udp-m udp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# END OPENVPN RULES

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

In my router (AVM FritzBox 6591 Cable) I have port forwarding for port 9000 to my raspberry pi active as you can see in this screenshot

[image]

However, when I enter "VPSIP:9000" in my browser, it simply times out. Where is something going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If the Raspberry Pi is running OpenVPN Client you don't need to open the port on your FritzBox router.
However the right iptables rule in PREROUTING is the one with 10.8.0.6 as destination

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:9000
-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p udp -m udp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:9000
```

The problem that the connection times out is because the Raspberry Pi receive a request through the VPN with a Public IP so the reply packets will go out through the Raspberry Pi Ethernet(or Wi-Fi interface) because doesn't have the routing rule to reply back via the VPN interface.
In order to don't touch anything on the RaspberryPi you can resolve this by masquerade the VPS WAN traffic with the VPN Server IP a quick example below:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o <vpn-server-interface> -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

The Raspberry Pi will see request coming from the VPN Server IP (assuming is 10.8.0.1)
So in the /etc/ufw/before.rules file should like

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:9000
-A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p udp -m udp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6:9000

# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to venet0 (change to the interface you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -o <vpn-server-interface> -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

**Note:** Drawback of this solution is that on the logs of the portainer application you will see all the request with the VPN Server IP

**EDIT:** IMHO the best way to achieve this is to use nginx or apache on the VPS as reverse proxy, in that way you don't need to setup any iptables prerouting and postrouting rules and plus you will have on the reverse proxy the logs with the clients real IPs

Comment: @musterknabe I edited my post for suggesting a reverse proxy instead of iptables rules it will be a more simple and clear solution

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunetely I tried an ssh tunnel instead and since this worked I don't really bother to make it work with OpenVPN.